# Stuck in GRUB command line, even after grub updates

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, grub, pop-os

I am dual booting PopOS and Windows 11 on my Dell Laptop.

Today I was doing some updates to nvidia drivers (probably unrelated) and after a reboot I was stuck inside the GRUB shell (not the rescue shell). This happens after every reboot.

I am able to boot to Pop OS after executing:

```
set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,1)
insmod linux
insmod normal
normal
```

I have multiple partitions, one for Windows, one for Linux and an EFI partition.
The boot order is to first boot a grub.efi file, but when I try to boot into Pop OS I get a kernel Error (Unable to mount root fs) like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0)

I ran the Boot Repair tool, but it stopped at purging GRUB, I couldn't get all off my system. This is the BootInfo summary: http://sprunge.us/K6bXA2

I obviously tried `sudo update-grub` and `grub-install` countless times with all imaginable partitions.

Maybe the problem is, that I have two EFI partitions (no idea how that happened), but there is only one GRUB, so I can't imagine what is wrong.

It would also be great, if somebody knows of any logs I can inspect. Kernel logs are sadly not helpful.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `I was stuck inside the GRUB shell (not the rescue shell)` If you need to `normal`, that IS the (grub's) rescue shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fortunately was able to solve it.

In the grub terminal, I ran `set` and grub was looking for the OS in `(hd0,gpt0)/EFI/ubuntu` but the files were located in `(hd0,gpt0)/EFI/pop`.
So I moved the files (like described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284787/grub-only-in-shell-mode-wrong-root-and-prefix-set)).

I have absolutely no idea how the directory changed.